# I can't find Google Oauth2.0 v2 Rest API docs

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api

Noob Struggling:
I want to create google oauth login on my express.js server. I'm trying to find google oauth2.0 REST API but can't seem to find any docs. although there are tutorials of what I want to do with it that contain the Rest API URLs, but I seriously can't find the rest. I somehow found some of the links from here https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
but these doesn't contain the querystring params